# I have to make a program that sorts 15 numbers from greatest to least, and then list the top five

Tags: c++11

I have to make a program that sorts 15 numbers from greatest to least, and then list the top five. Ive gotten some of it done. can someone help me on how to list the top five numbers?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 100

int main()
{

    int arr[MAX];
    int n,i,j;
    int temp;


    cout<<"Enter how many numbers to read: ";
    cin>>n;


    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter "<<i+1<<" number ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {       
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[i]<arr[j])
            {
                temp  =arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }


    cout<<"largest to smallest:"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    cout<<endl; 

    cout <<"the top five numbers are:"<< endl;



    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Sort in decrementing order and print till the count of 5 .

Answer (score 0):

Well you have already sorted it in descending order. 
So to get the top 5, you just have to print the first 5 numbers in your array.

```
for (i=0; i<5; i++) cout << arr[i] << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to have the top 5 elements, it is not necessary to sort the whole array. You can do a `std::partial_sort` to just have top 5 elements.

```
std::partial_sort(
   std::begin(arr), 
   std::begin(arr) + 5,
   std::end(arr), 
   [](int x, int y) { return x > y; });
```

Comment: thank you, we didn't learn how to use partial sort yet. I figured it out though!